# I don't understand the plus and minus voting on posts

Tags: discussion

I made a question post on stack overflow.  The next day there were about 10 views and there was a - 3 score on my unanswered (of course) question.  Does this mean that three people thought it was a bad question and are allowed to be anonymous judges?  What is the purpose of this anonymous voting?  Can I just page about all I want and dis people's questions?

Comment: Can you link to the said question? Maybe I can guess why it got downvotes. Just maybe..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731945/will-agsxmpp-only-work-with-net-1-1-or-2-0

Comment: [The other user has commented on why they think your post got downvoted.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731945/will-agsxmpp-only-work-with-net-1-1-or-2-0#comment64985414_38731945)

Comment: The question is off topic.  No surprise it's downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

All voting is anonymous (both positive and negative). If you hover over the downvote button, it reads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Hence was deemed to be that way by at least 3 users.

Your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731945/will-agsxmpp-only-work-with-net-1-1-or-2-0):

> What is it with the -3 ? Is anyone allowed to dis a question and remain anonymous? What kind of forum wienie behavior is this?

is not necessary, given the amount of time you have been a member, surely you know that the downvotes are not personal, and would know that they are related to the quality standards laid out in the help pages.

Also, Stack sites are *not* forums.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here's how it works

If you ask a question that people don't like, or for whatever reason, they downvote you.

You need 15 reputation to vote up, or as you say, plus voting.

You need 125 reputation to vote down, or minus voting.

Yes they are allowed to be anonymous judges. You are too. The purpose of this anonymous voting is to make sure that people don't ask a bunch of spam questions.

I presume you are talking about [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731945/will-agsxmpp-only-work-with-net-1-1-or-2-0)

> I am wanting to write an xmpp server on my .net server at my webhoster. The only free xmpp library I can find is agsxmpp. But the webpage there says it is only compatible with .net 1.1 or .net 2.0. So am I out of luck?
>
> thanks, Dean

People will downvote you if you ask a bad question.

## It's OK.

Losing reputation is not the end of the world.

Don't respond with hate comments. Or hate posts, for that matter.